# wrapper for common subset of auto_ptr and unique_ptr API

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, c++03

I read [an interesting old question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/291141/how-to-handle-design-changes-for-auto-ptr-deprecation-in-c11) on the Software Engineering SE about how to transition away from `std::auto_ptr`. So I wrote a wrapper around the common subset of `std::auto_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`.

The wrapper's mission in life at runtime is to clean up pointers created with `new` when the scope ends regardless of how the scope is exited. Its job at compile time is to make compilation fail as informatively as possible when `fake_autoptr` is used in a non-lowest-common-denominator way.

`fake_autoptr` is supposed to make it easier to transition away from `std::auto_ptr` and support both C++11 and C++03 until support for C++03 is dropped. It should behave the same way whether it is backed by an `auto_ptr` or a `unique_ptr`.

The example given in the old question is this. This example is not leveraging many of the things that an `autoptr` can do. I think, but am not 100% certain that the `autoptr`'s job here is just to run `delete` when its destructor is called and not to steal resources from other `autoptr`s.

```
// NOT MINE DO NOT REVIEW

Foo* GetFoo()
{
    autoptr<Foo> ptr(new Foo);

    // Initialize Foo
    ptr->Initialize(...);

    // Now configure remaining attributes
    ptr->SomeSetting(...);

    return ptr.release();
}
```

Here is the wrapper I came up with.

```
#ifndef FAKE_AUTOPTR_FAKE_AUTOPTR_INCLUDED
#define FAKE_AUTOPTR_FAKE_AUTOPTR_INCLUDED 1

#include <memory>
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <type_traits>
#endif

namespace fake_autoptr_ns {
  namespace detail {
    template <class T>
    void destroy(T* goner) {
      delete goner;
    }
  }

  template <class T>
  class fake_autoptr {
    public:
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(&detail::destroy<T>)> smartptr_;
      typedef decltype(smartptr_) smartptr_type;
#else
      std::auto_ptr<T> smartptr_;
      typedef std::auto_ptr<T> smartptr_type;
#endif


#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      fake_autoptr() = delete;
      ~fake_autoptr() = default;
#else
    private:
      fake_autoptr();
    public:
#endif


#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      template <class CtorArg>
      explicit fake_autoptr(CtorArg something) : smartptr_(something, detail::destroy<T>) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<T*, CtorArg>::value, "constructor argument must be T*");
      }
#else
      template <class CtorArg>
      explicit fake_autoptr(CtorArg something) : smartptr_(something) {}
#endif


      // delete special member functions
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      explicit fake_autoptr(const fake_autoptr<T>&) = delete;
      explicit fake_autoptr(fake_autoptr<T>&&) = delete;
      fake_autoptr& operator=(const fake_autoptr<T>&) = delete;
      fake_autoptr& operator=(fake_autoptr<T> &&) = delete;
#else
    private:
      explicit fake_autoptr(const fake_autoptr<T>&);
      fake_autoptr& operator=(const fake_autoptr<T>&);
    public:
#endif

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      T& operator*() = delete;
      T* get() = delete;
#endif

      const smartptr_type& operator->() const {
        return smartptr_;
      }

      smartptr_type& operator->() {
        return smartptr_;
      }

      T* release() {
        return smartptr_.release();
      }

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      const T* release() const = delete;

      void reset() = delete;

      void reset() const = delete;
#endif
  };
}

#endif // FAKE_AUTOPTR_FAKE_AUTOPTR_INCLUDED
```

This is less interesting, but here's a smoke test to make sure it works

```
#include "fake_autoptr.hpp"
#include <cstdio>

struct TwoInts {
  int int1;
  int int2;
  void print_first_int() {
    printf("1st %d\n", int1);
  }
  void print_second_int() {
    printf("2nd %d\n", int2);
  }
};


TwoInts* GetInt()
{
  using namespace fake_autoptr_ns;
  TwoInts *t = new TwoInts();
  t->int1 = 3;
  t->int2 = 7;
  fake_autoptr<TwoInts> ptr(t);
  ptr->print_first_int();
  ptr->print_second_int();
  return ptr.release();
}

int main() {
  TwoInts *t = GetInt();
  delete t;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your use-case better? When would I want to use `fake_autoptr<T>` in preference to `std::unique_ptr<T>`? The only advantage to `std::auto_ptr` is that it compiles as C++03... but your `fake_autoptr` is C++11-only, so *that's* not why you're using it. Why not just use `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @Quuxplusone, I've edited the code so it compiles as either C++11 or C++03 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a 100% convinced that you should put effort in supporting C++98/03. Especially since you can upgrade your code with [Clang tidy modernize](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-replace-auto-ptr.html) However, I see the arguments on moving slowly.

That said, your code looks good. However, I do have some remarks.

#ifdef is used a lot. So often, that one can wonder whether it makes sense to use a single ifdef with separate class definitions. It might improve the readability.

I really like the deleted methods and the shadow private variants. It can help a lot in ensuring the compatibility.

Looking at the stored unique_ptr, you use a helper function to delete the stored instance. WHY? This is what the default already does with a better implementation. (No extra memory needed) I don't see a compatibility argument as you don't use it with the auto_ptr.

I see the templated constructor, however, I don't see the point of having it as a template. Instead you could just use `T*` directly in the wrapper?

The thing I find the strangest is your `operator->` which doesn't return a raw pointer. Instead you expose the underlying storage in that signature.